# How to Login Using API with Model Class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api

How to Login Using API with Model Class in Flutter?

I have Json response as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "user": {
    "user_id": "609cab2cd5b6c",
    "name": "Test User",
    "mobile": "9909413561",
    "email": "sunil@gmail.com",
    "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
    "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344",
    "location": "Bardoli",
    "avatar": "upload/avatar/609cab2cd5b6c609cb9205afef.png",
    "device_id": "y",
    "created_at": "2021-05-13",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-13"
  },
  "plan_id": "0",
  "msg": "You have not purchased any plan"
}
```

Created  Model Class from above response in loginmodel.dart file as below.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final loginModel = loginModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

LoginModel loginModelFromJson(String str) =>
    LoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginModelToJson(LoginModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginModel {
  LoginModel({
    required this.success,
    required this.user,
    required this.planId,
    required this.msg,
  });

  int success;
  User user;
  String planId;
  String msg;

  factory LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginModel(
        success: json["success"],
        user: User.fromJson(json["user"]),
        planId: json["plan_id"],
        msg: json["msg"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "user": user.toJson(),
        "plan_id": planId,
        "msg": msg,
      };
}

class User {
  User({
    required this.userId,
    required this.name,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.email,
    required this.standardId,
    required this.mediumId,
    required this.location,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.deviceId,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  String userId;
  String name;
  String mobile;
  String email;
  String standardId;
  String mediumId;
  String location;
  String avatar;
  String deviceId;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        userId: json["user_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        mobile: json["mobile"],
        email: json["email"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
        location: json["location"],
        avatar: json["avatar"],
        deviceId: json["device_id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "user_id": userId,
        "name": name,
        "mobile": mobile,
        "email": email,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
        "location": location,
        "avatar": avatar,
        "device_id": deviceId,
        "created_at":
            "${createdAt.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${createdAt.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${createdAt.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "updated_at":
            "${updatedAt.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${updatedAt.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${updatedAt.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      };
}
```

And Created Function as below in apimanager.dart file.

```
Future<User> loginUser(
      String mobile, String standardid, String mediumid) async {
    final loginUrl = "$baseUrl/user/login";
    var data;
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(loginUrl), body: {
      'mobile': mobile,
      'standardid': standardid,
      'mediumid': mediumid,
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashBoard()));
      print(data);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed.');
    }
    return data;
  }
```

Here is my Login screen file login.dart as below.

```
class Login2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Login2State createState() => _Login2State();
}

class _Login2State extends State<Login2> {
  final baseUrl = SankalpApi().baseUrl;
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool value = false;
  var _standards = <Standard>[];
  var _mediums = <Medium>[];
  Standard? selectedStandard;
  Medium? selectedMedium;

  var standardId;
  var mediumId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ApiManager().getStandards().then((standards) {
      setState(() {
        _standards = standards;
      });
    });
  }

  void onMediumChange(standard) {
    setState(() {
      selectedStandard = standard;
      _mediums = [];
    });
    String mediumUrl =
        "$baseUrl/medium/get_by_course_id?standard_id=${selectedStandard?.standardId}";
    ApiManager().getMediums(mediumUrl).then((List<Medium> value) => {
          setState(() {
            _mediums = value;
          })
        });
  }

  final TextEditingController mobileController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 20, right: 10, left: 10),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: globalFormKey,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number"),
                  controller: mobileController,
                  //onSaved: (input) => userModel.mobile = input!,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                DropdownButton<Standard>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    hint: Text('Select Standard'),
                    value: selectedStandard,
                    items: _standards.map((Standard standard) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<Standard>(
                        value: standard,
                        child: Text(standard.standardName),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedStandard = val;
                        standardId = val!.standardId;
                        //print("StandardId : ${val.standardId}");
                        //print("StandardId : ${val.standardName}");
                        onMediumChange(val);
                      });
                    }),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                DropdownButton<Medium>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    hint: Text('Select Medium'),
                    value: selectedMedium,
                    items: _mediums.map((Medium medium) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<Medium>(
                        value: medium,
                        child: Text(medium.mediumName),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedMedium = val;
                        mediumId = val!.mediumId;
                        print("Medium id : ${val.mediumId}");
                        print("Medium id : ${val.mediumName}");
                      });
                    }),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      ApiManager().loginUser(
                          mobileController.text, standardId, mediumId);
                      //print("Mobile No : ${mobileController.text}");
                      //print("StandardId : ${standardId}");
                      //print("MediumId : ${mediumId}");
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Login'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am not able to log in.
in both DropDown i get the values perfectly, which medium is based on standard which also get by standardperfectly, but i am not able to log in please help.

Comment: What is the error, is there any error, or your data is just not showing?

Comment: in factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(----------------------- userId: json["user_id"], line   throws error..... ===> Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')